# Comparing strings with 2 names

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out how can I print two strings in alphabetical order.
Basically the user is asked to give names to the students, but he also needs to give their surnames.

My question is , if the first name is equal, how can I print them in alphabetical order without having to "re-do" the whole thing?

Example:

First student: **Mark Adele**

Second student: **Mark Boy**

**Struct:**

```
typedef struct
{
    int number;
    char name[10];
    char surname[10];
}num_nom_surname;
num_nom_surname *number_name_surname;
```

**This part can only compare the first name**

```
if (strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name)) < 0) 
{

   for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
   {
      printf("\n Student N%c %5d - ", 167, number_name_surname[i].number);
      printf("Name: %s %s", number_name_surname[i].name, number_name_surname[i].surname);
   }
}
else 
{
   for (i = number_of_students - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      printf("\n Student N%c %5d - ", 167, number_name_surname[i].number);
      printf("Name: %s %s", number_name_surname[i].name, number_name_surname[i].surname);
   }
}
printf("\n Value of strcmp: %d", strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name)));
```

Comment: What do you mean "re-do the whole thing"?

Comment: having another "if" inside the one i posted

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking.  You are trying to avoid another if statement?  Or are you trying to avoid `strcmp` again on `surname`s?  If it is the latter, you can store the results of `strcmp` in a variable before the if-statement and then refer to that in your future conditionals.

Comment: You could add another field to the struct to hold the full name? Compare that?

Comment: I was refering to the first thing you said, avoiding another if-statement. Anyway, my question is, how can I compare both things at the same time @ChristianGibbons.
Basically what I am saying is, how can I do it at the same time, not needing another if statement

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane so I can add "char fullname[10]" and compare that? But how do I join the first and the second name if I have a "space" between them?

Comment: You would have to add new strings that concatenate `name` and `surname`.  However it's better to just have another if statement that performs `strcmp` on surnames in the event that `strcmp` returns `0` for the names.

Comment: if `name` and `surname` each hold 9 characters (ignoring the NULL terminators), would you trust `fullname` to be able to fit all of that plus a NULL terminator in 10 chars?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons ok, I guess the second option is better, gonna use it and will check out the first one as well

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I mean of course I wouldn't, i would change it to 20, just to make sure